# Achar elemento que o ID é gerado randomicamente

Tags: python, random, selenium-webdriver

tenho uma situação que o id, sempre vai atualizando randomicamente..e sem uma ordem aparenteimpossibilitando eu usar o find_element_by_id

o componente é o seguinte:

```
<table id="treeview-2234-record-879" data-boundview="treeview-2234" data-recordid="879" data-recordindex="0" class="x-grid-item x-grid-item-selected" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
```

O que ja tentei?

- Usar o recordid, porem ele se repete em alguns casos
- Pela class_name existem outros componentes com a mesma classe
- Claro, pelo id..que como expliquei atualiza em todo refresh e é random
- Tentei pelo texto do elemento, porem sem sucesso.
- Pela raiz do treeview-2234, sem sucesso.

Sou mais uma vitima do `EXT`, alguma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a implementação do selenium para python permite você utilizar CSS e XPATH selectors isso é trivial, exemplos:

```
# XPATH

table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@data-recordid='879']")

# CSS

table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table[data-recordid='879']")
```

Comment: tambem se aplica a data-recordindex='0'?
não posso testa no momento..mas funciona?

Comment: Vai funcionar para qualquer seletor CSS|XPATH válido. Se você quiser testar se o seletor funciona "manualmente" antes de rodar o selenium é só abrir o console do seu browser na página que está testando e rodar algo assim:
`document.querySelectorAll("table[data-recordid='879']"); // CSS`
`$x("//table[@data-recordid='879']"); // XPATH, só funciona no chrome`

Comment: tentarei, obrigado pela reposta.

Comment: Se resolver o seu problema seria bom você marcar minhas resposta como a correta ;)

Comment: Com certeza irei,

Comment: Existem mais de um componente com o mesmo data-recordid, como posso contornar isso?